# Using colors in Scala Console

Tags: scala, console, intellij-idea

I was hoping that would be as straight forward as

```
Console.out.println( "Test " + Console.RED + " RED " + Console.RESET )
```

but nothing happens, instead I see the control characters (e.g. `"\033[31m"`). I tried both from within sbt (`sbt run`) and normal IDEA run configuration run...

Comment: I didn't know it was possible with Scala, +1 for the culture.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27229533/how-to-colorize-the-standard-output-in-scala-with-ansi-codes for an alternative to Console.RED and such.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It works if your console supports color.  I just tried it on a linux system via putty and got the expected result.

Edit:  If you're looking to do this via windows you can use [Ansicon](http://adoxa.3eeweb.com/ansicon/index.html) to provide coloring in your standard command prompt.

Comment: Ah ok, it seems to be a problem of the IntelliJ IDEA Console. While the sbt plugin for IDEA provides colors for sbt itself, it seems that the ANSI control codes of scala.Console are not supported. I tried running from a normal bash and it works.

Answer (score 6):

Yup, the above works just fine.
Also I've found that it's pretty neat to wrap those up as methods ".red" on String, like in this library https://github.com/ktoso/scala-rainbow

Lots of Ruby gems out there that do this, but not so much for Scala yet... :-)

Answer (score 5):

from Scala Standard Library:

```
import scala.io.AnsiColor._
println(s"${REVERSED}${BOLD}My name ist ${GREEN}Green!${RESET} default font")
```

works in IntelliJ console too

Answer (score 1):

If you're using scala 2.11+ you can use this library : https://github.com/backuity/ansi-interpolator

It uses a macro to transform your strings at compile time, and supports nesting:

```
ansi"Text containing ansi tags such as %bold{bold text} or %underline{can be %yellow{nested}}"

// you can also use string interpolation:
val someMsg = "hey"
ansi"My msg %bold{in bold: $someMsg}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the 1) basic colors, if you additionaly in need of 2) bright and 3) background colors, I recommend using Jansi, which offers the options summarized.

**build.sbt:**

> libraryDependencies += "org.fusesource.jansi" % "jansi" % "1.17.1"