# How to colorize the standard output in scala with ansi codes

Tags: scala, scala-macros

Is there a scala library that can help colorize text written to the standard output?

This library should take advantage of the scala string interpolation mechanic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using scala 2.11+ you can use this library : https://github.com/backuity/ansi-interpolator

It uses a macro to transform your strings at compile time, and supports nesting:

```
ansi"Text containing ansi tags such as %bold{bold text} or %underline{can be %yellow{nested}}"

// you can also use string interpolation:
val someMsg = "hey"
ansi"My msg %bold{in bold: $someMsg}"
```